# connect-mongodb-session store multiple sessions

Tags: mongodb, express, session

I use connect-mongodb-session for storing session data in MongoDB. I made a React client to fetch GET and POST data from and to the express server. Question is how to store session correctly in MongoDB?

My problem is with session storing in multiple times while I see same sessionid and connect.sid. Several new UserSessions record created in each get request.
Please see youtube screencast:
https://youtu.be/jO_M-ezXAjM

Here is the server code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const mongoDbStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const store = new mongoDbStore({
    uri: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/session',
    collection: 'UserSessions'
});

store.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

const sessionConfig = {
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: store,
    cookie: {
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        httpOnly: true
    }
}

app.use(session(sessionConfig));

const corsOptions = {
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    credentials: true,
    origin: true,
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.post('/api/auth', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session);
    res.send({ message: 'welcome to a simple HTTP cookie server' });
});

app.get('/api/users/me', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session);
    res.send({ name: 'Test Elek' });
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('The server is running port 8080...'));
```

Here is the fetch from client side:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/users/me`, {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: "include",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            cache: 'no-cache'
        })

fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/auth`, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: "include",
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            cache: 'no-cache'
        })
```

Please help me find the misstake.

Comment: Please provide the code directly instead of a link to a video.

Comment: code included now in question. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was handle OPTIONS requests in express as following:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, x-auth-token');

    if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});
```

I tried with Redis and the resolution was same as MongoDB.
I use CORS for React fetch and Express and this generate OPTIONS requests, and because OPTIONS has no authentication headers, requests made new sessions. Sessionid persistent for GET and POST requests.